# facebook php sdk login error :- you are not connected

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use facbook-php-sdk https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk to implement a simple login with facebook. The code works for some people but not for others. I am trying to get all the permissions and display the data in json format on next page.

This is the output that comes after people allow all permissions and go to the next page:-
[image: Error Image]

This is the code I am using:-

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2560M');
// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.
$limit = 1000;
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $statuses = $facebook->api("/me/statuses?limit=$limit");
    $albums = $facebook->api("/me/albums?limit=$limit");
    $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes?limit=$limit");
    $activities = $facebook->api("/me/activities?limit=$limit");
    $posts = $facebook->api("/me/posts?limit=$limit");
    $events = $facebook->api("/me/events?limit=$limit");
    $notes = $facebook->api("/me/notes?limit=$limit");
    $checkins = $facebook->api("/me/checkins?limit=$limit");
    $friendlists = $facebook->api("/me/friendlists?limit=$limit");
    $friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends?limit=$limit");
    $groups = $facebook->api("/me/groups?limit=$limit");
    $interests = $facebook->api("/me/interests?limit=$limit");
    $photos = $facebook->api("/me/photos?limit=$limit");
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'email, user_actions.music, user_activities, user_events, user_hometown, user_location, user_questions, user_religion_politics, user_videos, publish_actions, user_actions.news, user_birthday, user_games_activity, user_interests, user_notes, user_relationship_details, user_status, user_website, user_about_me, user_actions.video, user_education_history, user_groups, user_likes, user_photos, user_relationships, user_subscriptions, user_work_history, friends_about_me, friends_actions.video, friends_education_history, friends_groups, friends_likes, friends_photos, friends_relationships, friends_subscriptions, friends_work_history, friends_actions.music, friends_activities, friends_events, friends_hometown, friends_location, friends_questions, friends_religion_politics, friends_videos, friends_actions.news, friends_birthday, friends_games_activity, friends_interests, friends_notes, friends_relationship_details, friends_status, friends_website, ads_management, export_stream, manage_notifications, photo_upload, read_friendlists, read_page_mailboxes, rsvp_event, status_update, xmpp_login, create_event, friends_online_presence, manage_pages, publish_checkins, read_insights, read_requests, share_item, user_online_presence, create_note, manage_friendlists, offline_access, publish_stream, read_mailbox, read_stream, sms, video_upload'
  ));
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>Approves it</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Approves it</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
      <?php print_r($user); ?>
      <h3>User Profile</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($user_profile)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Statuses</h3>
      <?php foreach ($statuses['data'] as $status): ?>
          <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($status)); ?></pre>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <h3>Albums</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($albums)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Likes</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($likes)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Activities</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($activities)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Posts</h3>
      <?php foreach ($posts['data'] as $post): ?>
          <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($post)); ?></pre>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      <h3>Events</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($events)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Notes</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($notes)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Checkins</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($checkins)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Friend Lists</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($friendlists)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Friends</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($friends)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Groups</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($groups)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Interests</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($interests)); ?></pre>
      <h3>Photos</h3>
      <?php foreach ($photos['data'] as $photo): ?>
          <pre><?php print_r(json_encode($photo)); ?></pre>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected. Please login with facebook.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The error can be reproduced by visiting the site:- http://approvesit-data.alphabetalabs.com/

Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION : This worked for me after trying for many solutions for this issue.

In      base_facebook.php        file, find the makeRequest() method and check for following Line.

```
$opts = self::$CURL_OPTS;
```

Immediately following it, add this line

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
```

Comment: Might prove helpful for someone.I can't verify if its the correct solution as I am no longer working on that issue.